# How to quit flash mode on HM-10?

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-leonardo, ble

I have an HM-10 BLE module connected to Arduino Leonardo. It forwards UART from my computer:

```
#define btSerial Serial1

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);

    while (!Serial) {
        delay(50);
    }

    Serial.println("Initialized on 9600");

    btSerial.begin(9600);
    while (!btSerial) {
        delay(50);
    }

    Serial.println("BT initialized on 9600");
}

void loop() {
    if (btSerial.available()) {
        Serial.write(btSerial.read());
    }

    if (Serial.available()) {
        btSerial.write(Serial.read());
    }
}
```

In general, it works fine, but I've decided to flash it and sent `AT+SBLUP` command to it, and it's in flash mode now.

Later I've realized that I can't flash it because Parallels Desktop's COM forwarding does not work fine (I work on macOS).

And now I can't quit from the flash mode — it just does not respond to AT commands (however, `btSerial` is alive).

I've tried to reset the Arduino, disconnect BT for several minutes — it's still in flash mode. How to quit this mode?

Comment: you must flash some firmware

Comment: If you disconnected power from the HM-01 and it's still in flash mode the next time you power it, I would guess, that entering flash mode erases the firmware. Thus you would have to burn a new firmware to it. But thats just a guess